# What is the difference between Continuous-Time and Continuous Value in signals?

Tags: signal

[image]

[image]  I do not understand the difference between Continuous Value and Continuous-time. Discrete-time and discrete value. Can anybody offer a clearer explanation?

Comment: Context is needed.

Comment: @Andyaka I have updated the post! :)

Comment: Well, the additions to your answer are self-explanatory (to me) so, what is it that you don't understand about them? The continuous time and continuous value signals are identical if that helps?

Comment: @Andyaka  I do not understand the difference between time & value

Comment: Value is usually amplitude of measured signal in some units, like volts, amperes,  meters etc.

Comment: It's a bad presentation : in both pictures the LH image is both continuous time and continuous value, which doesn't help. But notice that one RHS has value defined at all points in time (cont time) but only assumes 4 values (discrete value) while the other can assume any value, but only at specific times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I do not understand the difference between time & value*

Time is along the x horizontal axis and, value is on the y vertical axis. The signal in the top diagram (left) and the bottom diagram (left) is both continuous in time and continuous in value in that there are no sudden changes in either axis.